# Missing headers with imakeidx' index

Tags: header-footer, imakeidx

The MCE and images below point out that, with `imakeidx`' index, some headers may be missing, e.g. on the:

- even page (chapter stuff) just before index 1st page (the index starting on an odd page, *just* at its top),
- index 1st page (the index starting on an odd page, *not* at its top).

Do you see how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[papersize=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,noclearpage}

\makeindex

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \chapter{Foo}
  \section{Bar}

  Baz\index{Baz}

  \lipsum[1-#1]

  \printindex
}

\begin{document}
% Missing header on the even page (6) just before index 1st page (7)
\test{8}
% Missing header on index 1st page (13)
\test{5}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `imakeidx` sets the page style of the first page of the index to `plain`. You need to keep it as `headings`.

Change your `\indexsetup` to:

```
\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,noclearpage,firstpagestyle=headings}
```

You could probably make a case that `imakeidx` should not change the heading style when the `noclearpage` option is set. But I'm a little cautious about telling the author of that particular package what to do! :)

Comment: Sigh, I should not have missed that :( Anyway, I will be much more brave than you! ;)